# How can i make a view like CollapsingToolbarLayout with ReactNative?

Tags: react-native, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, react-native-reanimated

I want make a view like [this](https://yojigen.tech/13/1.gif), or like this [video](https://mouyase.notion.site/RN-f9af8aa4aa0a4e0bb1319bf9ba4aba94)

I used [react-native-collapsible-tab-view](https://github.com/PedroBern/react-native-collapsible-tab-view) but it is have bugs.

Can I make it with react-native-reanimated and react-native-gesture-handler?

Here is the page structure

```
<View>
  <Animated.View>
    <FastImage
    style={{weidth: '100%', height: '200'}}
    source={{
      uri: 'some_image.jpg',
    }}
  />
  </Animated.View>
  <Animated.View>
    <TabsProvider defaultIndex={0}>
      <Tabs>
        <TabScreen label='Tab1'>
          <ScrollView>
            <Text>SomeViews</Text>
          </ScrollView>
        </TabScreen>
        <TabScreen label='Tab2'>
          <ScrollView>
            <Text>SomeViews</Text>
          </ScrollView>
        </TabScreen>
      </Tabs>
    </TabsProvider>
  </Animated.View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can

- pass onScroll prop to ScrollView form either "react-native" or
  "react-native-gesture-handler",
- use useSharedValue from "react-native-reanimated" and update it in
  handleScroll,
- add shared value to useAnimatedStyle from "react-native-reanimated", and
- pass animStyle to the cover view.

Exapmple:

```
  const animProgress = useSharedValue(0);

  const handleScroll = ({ nativeEvent }) => {
    animProgress.value = Math.min(1, nativeEvent.contentOffset.y / disapearLimit);
  };

  const animStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
    transform: [ { scaleY: 1 + animProgress.value * (disapearLimit / coverHeight - 1) }, ],
    opacity: 1 - animProgress.value,
  }));

  return (
    <View>
      <Animated.View style={[styles.coverViewWithAbsolutePosition, animStyle]} />
      <View>
        <ScrollView onScroll={handleScroll} scrollEventThrottle={16}>
          {children}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
```

Alternatively, props passed to useAnimatedStyle could be generated by useDerivedValue.